# How do I define class output in ipython console

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, ipython

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class PrintStuff:
    def __init__(self,stuff):
        self._stuff = stuff

    def __str__(self):
        return self._stuff
```

If I make an instance of it in ipython and type the name of the instance, it prints out what appears to be the name of the class and the location of it in memory. However if I put the instance into the print function, it prints out as expected:

```
pstuff = PrintStuff('print this stuff')

pstuff
Out[44]: <__main__.PrintStuff at 0x7fae0531de80>

print(pstuff)
print this stuff
```

How would I go about making it so that the ipython console prints the same stuff that the print function does? For example, a pandas series has the type of behavior I am looking for:

```
series = pd.Series({'x':[1,2],'y':[2,3],'z':[3,4]})

series
Out[47]: 
x    [1, 2]
y    [2, 3]
z    [3, 4]
dtype: object

print(series)
x    [1, 2]
y    [2, 3]
z    [3, 4]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `__repr__`:

By default, the Object `__repr__` returns the type and memory address, this is what you see when the console outputs (for instance):

`<__main__.PrintStuff at 0x7fae0531de80>`

After overloading the `__repr__`, you control what the output is.

```
class PrintStuff:
    def __init__(self,stuff):
        self._stuff = stuff

    def __str__(self):
        return self._stuff

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


pstuff = PrintStuff('print this stuff')
pstuff
```

#### output:

```
print this stuff
```